# software & updates didn't open in Ubuntu 16.04. How to fix it?

Tags: updates

In Ubuntu 16.04, I tried to open the `software & updates`. But didn't open. If I click to software & updates icon,It will show on launcher pad and blinking around 15sec. And automatically closing.

The instructions offered were GREAT!  But, it took a while to understand EXACTLY The suggested steps.  Therefore, I'm restating them for newbees like me.

1. Open the terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>.
2. type `sudo apt update` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. type `sudo apt upgrade` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. you will answer the question by typing or selecting `Y` and press
   <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
5. now, please wait a long time while a process
   goes on.  A bar shows slow progress up to 100%.
6. restart the computer.

The results were GREAT.  It solved my Ubuntu software problem, the SW update problem, continuous "system error" messages, AND a failed network that I had painfully constructed.  Remember, I'm a NEWBEE and wish I knew more about Unix.

Comment: Open the terminal using `Ctrl + Alt + t` then type `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y` and press `Enter` after that try to open it and see if it stays open

Comment: I don't know if @George's suggestion will help but it's worth a try. You'll probably have to use Ctrl + *Alt* + T to open the Terminal. Then keep the Terminal open and try running Software & Updates again. if it fails again, type `software-properties-gtk` in the Terminal and press Enter. This will probably also fail to open Software & Updates but the output may be helpful. Select *all* text in the Terminal from the beginning of the line on which you typed the first command to the end of the output from `software-properties-gtk`, copy it to the clipboard, and **[edit]** your question to add it.

Comment: Sorry.This is not getting.I already tried this commands.But didn't work.

Comment: OK then do as Eliah has said and post the output into your question...

Comment: Sorry George ,That also didn't work. I tried to the terminal.It is properly run and not showing any issue.But my issue didn't fix it .

Comment: Please open it from the `System Settings...` option, top right of your screen. Where you normally log out from. `System Settings --> Software & Updates`

Comment: I will go like you told way.But I can't select the icon.If i click the software & updates icon,didn't show any thing

Comment: George,I checked with Eliah has said way.Then I got like this.....

Comment: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.PermissionsInvalid: The permission of the setuid helper is not correct

Comment: Try this command using terminal, software-properties-gtk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed my issues with the help of Eliah and George. They gave some hints. So I can clear this issues. I said thanks to both of them.

These are commands so I can fix the issue.

The following command is used as change the access permissions to file system objects (files and directories):

```
sudo chmod u+s /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper
```

Restart the dbus services:

```
sudo service dbus restart
```

If you open with the terminal and type `software-properties-gtk`, sometimes it will show some error like this:

> "permissions of the setuid helper is not correct"

Then use above commands.

Answer (score 1):

**New install of Software & update helped me**

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-gtk
```

**Now reinstall all the supporting packages:**

```
sudo aptitude reinstall apt apt-utils aptdaemon aptdaemon-data update-manager update-manager-core dbus
```